# How to sum items of a list of list respectively and make it one list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, sum

I have a dictionary that its value is a list of list. I want to sum up the first item in list 1 with the first item in list 2 with .... to the end, and then do it for all the items. in the end, I will have one list as a value for my dict. all of the lists have the same length.

> `my_dict = {'r1': [[0,1,0,1],[1,1,0,1],[0,1,1,1],[1,0,0,1]] , 'r2' : [[1,0,0,0],[1,1,0,0],[0,1,1,0],[1,0,0,1]]}`

result :

```
   my_dict = {'r1':[2,3,1,4], 'r2' : [3,2,1,1]}
```

Comment: You want the sum for each sublist in the list? That's just `[sum(sublist) for sublist in list]`. If you want to do that for each value in the dict, you can write a dict comprehension. If you don't understand comprehensions, try writing an explicit nested chain of `for` statements that build up a new dict by building up new lists out of sums of sublists.

Comment: `my_dict['r1'] = [sum(values) for values in zip(*my_dict['r1'])]`

Comment: @PeterWood Should not that be posted as an answer rather than a comment, since it seems to be a good solution?

Comment: Thanks @PeterWood that works, but what if I have 10000 keys and cannot type them manually to sum their values?

Comment: `my_dict = {key: [sum(values) for values in zip(*sublists)] for key, sublists in my_dict.items()}`

Answer (score 1):

You could use a dict comprehension:

```
new_dict = {k: list(map(sum, zip(*v))) for k, v in my_dict.items()}
```

The key idea here is zip(*v), which transforms your list of lists into a list of lists of the i-th elements:

```
zip(*[[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8]])   # returns [[1, 5], [2, 6], [3, 7], [4, 8]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
my_dict = {'r1': [[0,1,0,1],[1,1,0,1],[0,1,1,1],[1,0,0,1]] , 'r2' : [[1,0,0,0],[1,1,0,0],[0,1,1,0],[1,0,0,1]]}

print({i:map(lambda x:sum(x),zip(*j)) for i,j in my_dict.items()})
```

output:

```
{'r1': [2, 3, 1, 4], 'r2': [3, 2, 1, 1]}
```

Answer (score 0):

This operation would be much simpler with numpy.

You could try something like this:

```
import numpy as np
result = {}
for k in my_dict:
    v = np.array(my_dict[k]).sum(axis=0).tolist()
    result[k] = v
```